Changing SSID - Tuya Wifi door lock
I bought this product and it works well.
After installation I had to change my SSIDs, and now the doorlock is not connected the the internet.
I tried to recreate the exact SSID as before, but I guess i'm failing doing that.
My goal is to enter again to pair mode and re-define the new SSID. I don't find any documentation about it, or even factory reset.
Appreciate any help
Guy

Doesn’t the app connect to the lock via BLE? Can’t you use that to change settings or reset it?

it should probably only at time of pairing. After that this feature is not active, guessing it has something to do with security.

For any future use: *123456#9123456#
Edit: 123456 is default master code. After entering this code, pairing mode is available.

What does this do? A factory reset? Re-enable pairing? Does it mean anyone can reset the lock and take control of it just by entering that code?

@jcaron - answer edited. My goal was to regain pairing mode, as noted very clearly in question. Please undo down-vote.

I didn’t downvote. You mean one has to enter *mastercode#9mastercode#?
